# How to reduce image size captured with CameraX on Android?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm trying to understand how to use CameraX by studying [this example](https://github.com/clint22/CameraXExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/cameraxexample/MainActivity.kt):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        requestPermission()

        // Set up the listener for take photo button
        camera_capture_button.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() }

        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        // Create time-stamped output file to hold the image
        val photoFile = File(
            outputDirectory,
            SimpleDateFormat(
                FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US
            ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"
        )

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                }

                override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, msg)
                }
            })
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .build()

            val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, LuminosityAnalyzer { luma ->
                        Log.d(TAG, "Average luminosity: $luma")
                    })
                }

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer
                )

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }


    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
        }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    private fun requestPermission() {

        if (CameraUtility.hasCameraPermissions(this)) {
            startCamera()
            return
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this,
                "You need to accept the camera permission to use this app",
                REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_PERMISSION,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            )
        } else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this,
                "You need to accept the camera permission to use this app",
                REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_PERMISSION,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA

            )
        }

    }
```

It works. The images captured with this code are rather big. On Pixel 3, it produces  4032x3024 JPEGs (usually around 4.5 to 6 MB). Does CameraX has a built-in feature to reduce the JPEG size?

I tried this:

```
imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
    .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
    .setTargetResolution(Size(800, 600))
    .build()
```

and this:

```
 val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        .setTargetResolution(Size(800,600))
        .build()
        .also {
            it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, LuminosityAnalyzer { luma ->
             
            })
        }
```

Doesn't work. Still get the same 4032x3024 JPEG. I wonder if I don't understand the CameraX API properly.

Comment: You may have better luck choosing [an actual resolution supported by the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60901831/115145) for your `ImageCapture.Builder`, rather than 800x600.